# retrive json values from another site to current site

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

How to get json values from url

**url:**

```
admin-ajax.php?action=cfdb-login&cfdb-action=cfdb-export&form=contact%20form%20mail&enc=JSON&user_login=admin&user_password=admin
```

Content:

```
values
[
{"Submitted":"2014-11-06 10:44:29 +00:00","your-name":"ayyan","your-email":"test@mail.com","your-subject":"demo testing","your-message":"ayyantesting","Submitted Login":"admin","Submitted From":"127.0.0.1"},
{"Submitted":"2014-11-06 08:31:32 +00:00","your-name":"demo","your-email":"demo@mail.com","your-subject":"demo testing","your-message":"test the demo details","Submitted Login":"admin","Submitted From":"127.0.0.1"},
{"Submitted":"2014-11-06 08:18:26 +00:00","your-name":"ayyan","your-email":"test@mail.com","your-subject":"downloading hotel website","your-message":"test","Submitted Login":"admin","Submitted From":"127.0.0.1"}
]
```

i need to use this data to my current site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = "htp://www.example.com". /* Don't forget the http www part! */
    "admin-ajax.php?action=cfdb-login&cfdb-action=cfdb-export&form=contact%20form%20mail&enc=JSON&user_login=admin&user_password=admin";
$variable = json_decode(file_get_contents( $url ));
print_r($variable);
```